# Changing the price of product while adding to cart in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Hi thanks in advance,
How to change the price of product while adding to cart in woocommerce either by using hooks? 
Any suggesion**

Answer (score 1):

It involve five steps.

1) Store the extra product price ( in session ) while adding to cart.

2) Add the extra price while woocommerce do the cart total action

3) Render altered product price in cart page

4) Render altered product price in checkout order review section

5) Finally add the meta data in order line item.